# C Programming -- value swapping is making new value in random array slot

Tags: c, arrays, random

This is the array:

```
int deck [52] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11};
for(i = 0; i < 52; i++){
```

I'm using this to swap 2 values in the same array:

```
    randomNum1 = rand()%53;
    randomNum2 = rand()%53;
    temp = deck[randomNum1];
    deck[randomNum1] = deck[randomNum2];
    deck[randomNum2] = temp;
 }
```

I put in print statments to see if I could locate a specific number in the array that is going wonky:

```
for(i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    randomNum1 = rand()%53;
    randomNum2 = rand()%53;
    printf("This is the random number 1: %d\n", randomNum1);
    printf("This is the random number 2: %d\n", randomNum2);
    temp = deck[randomNum1];
    printf("This is the temp and deck[randomNum1] BEFORE: %d and %d\n", temp, deck[randomNum1]);
    deck[randomNum1] = deck[randomNum2];
    printf("deck[randomnum1]AFTER: %d\n", deck[randomNum1]);
    printf("deck[randomNum2]BEFORE: %d\n", deck[randomNum2]);
    deck[randomNum2] = temp;
    printf("deck[randomNum2]AFTER: %d\n", deck[randomNum2]);
}
```

The value spot that it goes in is always random, and it becomes a large number.
Print out from Compiler:

> 1. This is the random number 1: 52
> 2. This is the random number 2: 1
> 3. This is the temp and deck[randomNum1] BEFORE: 2271744 and 2271744
> 4. deck[randumNum1]AFTER: 3
> 5. deck[randomNum2]BEFORE:3
> 6. deck[randomNum2]AFTER: 2271744

Another Compiler Run:

> 1. This is the random number 1: 4
> 2. This is the random number 2: 16
> 3. This is the temp and deck[randomNum1] BEFORE: 4 and 4
> 4. deck[randumNum1]AFTER: 2271744
> 5. deck[randomNum2]BEFORE: 2271744
> 6. deck[randomNum2]AFTER: 4

There is a couple if statements and a while loop before this, but neither of which touch the values in this array. Any suggestions?

Comment: `deck[52]` is not a valid index. Try `rand() % 52` instead.

Comment: I feel like such a dunce now... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are going out of bounds of the `deck` array as the valid indexes of it start from 0 and end at 51. You try to access index 52 which results in Undefined Behavior.

To avoid this,use

```
randomNum1 = rand()%52;
randomNum2 = rand()%52;
```